# Show certain text in TextView Single Line

Tags: java, android, textview

For example, this is the original string s

Google
Android
Gmail
Youtube
Apple
iOS

```
<TextView
        android:id="@+id/text"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="1"
        android:maxLines="1"
        android:textSize="16sp" />
```

In the `TextView`, when I use `android:maxLines="1"`, only the first line, i.e Google will be visible. Is it possible to make the `TextView` show other text, for example Youtube in the first line without modifying the original string?

Answer (score 0):

I don't think there is any way to do that but you can save your string in an array form and use the word that you want to display.

```
myArray[0] = Google
myArray[1] = Android
myArray[2] = Gmail
myArray[3] = Youtube
myArray[4] = Apple
myArray[5] = iOS
```